# Picklist merge field in email template returns api name

Tags: visualforce, email-template

The merge field in my email template returns api name. Is there a way to display the label instead

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Notifcication Email" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="testobj__c">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
<apex:repeat value="{!relatedTo.Children__r}" var="cap" >
<apex:outputText value="{!cap.Picklist1__c}" /> 
</apex:repeat>
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

cap.Picklist1__c returns api name.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to include your markup if you desire help. Some demonstration of the observed output would also be a good idea to add. The more specific you are about the problem you face, the better your chances of a positive response and useful answer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `<apex:outputText value="{!cap.Picklist1__c}" />`

Use `<apex:outputField value="{!cap.Picklist1__c}" />`

Answer (score 0):

`{!$ObjectType.testobj__c.fields['{!cap.Picklist1__c}'].label}` will give you the label. your question is not clear though

Comment: The merge field in my email template returns api name for the "Picklist value". I want to display the label for the picklist value.